# Should table-valued parameters be used here?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

I have following query:

```
 @"UPDATE students SET IsDeleted = 1 WHERE StudentId IN (
         SELECT StudentId FROM Class where PassId IN (
              SELECT Id FROM ClassValueTable WHERE IsDeleted <> 1" 
                + activeIds)))";
```

where activeIds = string of some numbers for example: 1,2,3,4...

I want to convert this query into stored procedure. My question is what is the best way to pass activeIds as a parameter to this stored procedure?

*Code is in C# and am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) (however, i don't know if C#3 knows `SqlDbType.Structured`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - activeIds is just a string. Cant i just pass it as a string?

Comment: Not and use table-valued parameters. Why does it need to be a string? Doesn't it come from a collection at some point? Why convert it to a string only to have to split it up into a non-string? If you're going to do that, just keep using the SQL injection haven you're using now...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use table-valued parameters. First create a type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StudentIDs(ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now your procedure can use this (note that I've changed your nested `IN` queries to a proper join):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MarkStudentsAsDeleted
  @IDs dbo.StudentIDs READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE s SET IsDeleted = 1
    FROM dbo.Students AS s
    INNER JOIN dbo.Class AS c
    ON s.StudentId = c.StudentId
    INNER JOIN dbo.ClassValueTable AS ct
    ON c.PassId = ct.Id
    WHERE ct.IsDeleted <> 1
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @IDs WHERE StudentID = s.StudentID);
END 
GO
```

And your C# code would pass in a DataTable or however you've assembled the collection of activeIds, rather than a comma-separated list.

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add(1);
dt.Rows.Add(2);
dt.Rows.Add(3);
dt.Rows.Add(4);

... open connection etc. ...

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MarkStudentsAsDeleted", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter tvp1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDs", dt);
tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

... close, dispose, etc. ...
```

If you want to insist on passing a string into the stored procedure, you'll need to use a split function. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  VARCHAR(255) = ','
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
  RETURN 
  (  
    SELECT [value] = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
    FROM 
    ( 
      SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
        + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
        + '</i>').query('.')
    ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
  );
GO
```

Now your stored procedure can be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MarkStudentsAsDeleted
  @IDs VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE s SET IsDeleted = 1
    FROM dbo.Students AS s
    INNER JOIN dbo.Class AS c
    ON s.StudentId = c.StudentId
    INNER JOIN dbo.ClassValueTable AS ct
    ON c.PassId = ct.Id
    WHERE ct.IsDeleted <> 1
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitInts(@IDs, ',') WHERE Item = s.StudentID);
END 
GO
```

Comment: Actually i already have activeIds in a string like "1,2,3,..". That is why i was asking if it makes sense to still use value parameters or just pass it as a string in one parameter? Sorry new to this value parameter. And thanks a lot for great example! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @NoviceMe I get it, but where did this comma-separated string *come from*? The sky? You must have *assembled* it in some way at some point...

Comment: I get list from a folder and is saved in code as IEnumerable then i am using String.Join to make a comma seperated list. Hope i am able to explain it now?

Comment: See, you are taking a set, converting it to a list, only so SQL Server can then take your list and convert it back to a set. You can do exactly what I've done above replacing the `DataTable` stuff with `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`, and now you don't have to do any of this `String.Join` and split nonsense. Much more efficient and much less code. Please don't try to force JSON mentality onto SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining i will try it!

Comment: Sorry to bother again: I have created the stored procedure. But am stuck at c# code. I have all ids stored in: IEnumerable<IDs>, how can i pass it directly to the stored procedure?

Comment: In my sample code, I have a `DataTable` named `dt`. Do you see where `dt` is referenced later in the code? Try replacing that with the name of your IEnumerable.

Comment: I replaced IDs with dt. But am getting following error: Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1