# filter QSqlRelationalTableModel with setFilter function to show only items that contains a specific tag/tags

Tags: qt, sqlite, tagging, qtsql, qsqltablemodel

I have an `SQLITE` Database with the following tables

```
items(item_id,item_name,....);
tags(tag_id,tag_name);
items_tags(item_id,tag_id);
```

I'm using `QSqlRelationalTableModel` class to for the items table.

this class have this function `QSqlTableModel::setFilter(const QString &filter);`

The filter is a SQL WHERE clause without the keyword WHERE

for example: setFilter("item_name=arg");

what I want to do is to use the setFilter function to select only items with a specific tag/tags.

since I can only use the `setFilter(QString &Filter)` function which is basically a WHERE clause

I found this solution which I think is a bad one

I'll use this filter

```
setFilter(FilterString);


FilterString="item_id=arg1 or item_id=arg2 or item_id=argX or......"
```

the IDs will be obtained from this query

```
Query.prepare("select item_id from items_tags where tag_id=?");
```

the FilterString will be generated and incremented by a (do while loop) using `Query.next()` function that will loop over the resulted Query IDs

```
FilterString+="item=Query.value(item_id).toString();
```

and use like 2 if statements to determine when to add the `or` clause to the `FilterString`

this solution will definitely work but I think it's stupid because if there are many tagged items(say 5000) the Query string will contain 4999 `or` clause and another 5000 `"id=x"` so the Query will be more than 10000 characters long.

QString object can contain a lot more characters but is this Query will have a big impact on performance ?

what are the other alternatives, Even if it requires to switch to another DB like ORACLE or Mysql since SQLITE doesn't have many internal features

Comment: is it like a subscribe to some category or item tags to get updates of new items/arrivals ?

Comment: no, I'm having a BuyList software, which are basically items I have brought for my self like Electronics, furniture ,other,

I have three levels of categories and even a state field(whishlist,brought items) field....but the tags are for another thing

I wan't to use the tags for something like

(home theater project,setup,living room,important,optional)

there are a lot of items that can be tagged with such tags

like TV, furniture items and a lot of other items

Comment: @sadeq, I am not finding a reason why you are using filter here, you already query the DB down to what you want .. both _query_ and filter take strings **you are doubling the work**

Comment: @sadeq, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532192/using-in-in-a-where-clause-where-the-number-of-items-in-the-set-is-very-large

Comment: thanks, this is useful !
@MohammadKanan